# List div won't become horizontal with flex using Tailwind CSS with ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a header with the Title in the center, the logout button at the right, and a horizontal list menu at the bottom.

I'm using Tailwind CSS for styling, but the list won't become horizontal no matter what I throw at it.

```
import React from 'react'

function Header(props) {
 return (
<section className="text-black bg-white">        
    
    {/* MAIN TEXT AND USER LOGIN/LOGOUT */}
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center p-6">
      <h1 className="text-6xl px-3 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-lmgray">
          NEW STREET JOURNAL
      </h1>
      <div className="absolute right-20 mt-2 px-5 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-lmgray" >
          <p>{props.name}</p>  
          <button className="border-2 border-solid border-black rounded-md ">Logout</button> 
      </div>

    </div>
    

    {/* NAVBAR */}
    <div className="">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Home
      </li>
      <li>
        World
      </li>
      <li>
        India
      </li>
      <li>
        Politics
      </li>
      <li>
        Economy
      </li>
      <li>
        Markets
      </li>
      <li>
        Opinion
      </li>
      <li>
        Real Estate
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

    
</section>
  )
  }

Header.defaultProps={
title: 'News Feed'
}

export default Header
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `inline` display to all the list items, for example:

```
<li className="inline">
  Home
</li>
```

Alternatively, you can use divs instead of unordered lists, and use flexbox in the parent div as such:

```
<div className="flex">
  <div>
    Home
  </div>
  <div>
    World
  </div>
  <div>
    India
  </div>
  <div>
    Politics
  </div>
  <div>
    Economy
  </div>
  <div>
    Markets
  </div>
  <div>
    Opinion
  </div>
  <div>
    Real Estate
  </div>
</div>
```

The second method might be better as it allows you to control the styling from one parent div rather than having to change it for each child.